# git diff head minus one logic always returns true value and would deploy app

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

**Scenario**
We have several apps with 5-7 services each. Currently we individually call services under each app individually that means we have to maintain several pipelines. I'm trying to consolidate them so we repeatedly call build template for each service but in a single yaml file.

For the purpose I'm working on following logic

```
stages:
- stage: one
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: ${{ parameters.serviceName }}
      persistCredentials: true
      fetchDepth: 0
    - bash: |
          cd ${{ parameters.serviceName }}          
          **git diff HEAD^:src/docker-dotnet-app-aks HEAD:src/docker-dotnet-app-aks --exit-code --quiet**
          if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then 
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipsubsequent1;isOutput=true]true"
          else
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipsubsequent1;isOutput=true]false"
          fi
      name: skipstep
```

as you can see i pass a path to the folder to git diff head minus one and head.

**Problem**
git diff always finds the logic "git diff minus one" to be true unless i commit a change outside the folder. I need help to understand what logic or procedure i should adopt

I'm not sure what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this command always returns 1, unless you commit a change outside the folder, is that you are comparing the entire working tree with the parent commit, not just the folder. If you want to compare only the folder, you need to specify the path after the commit, like this:

```
**git diff HEAD~1:src/docker-dotnet-app-aks --exit-code --quiet**
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff),

- `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` compares the version before the last commit and the last commit.
- `HEAD^:src/docker-dotnet-app-aks`: This refers to the state of the `src/docker-dotnet-app-aks` directory in the first parent of the current commit.
- `HEAD:src/docker-dotnet-app-aks`: This refers to the state of the `src/docker-dotnet-app-aks` directory in the current commit.
- `--exit-code`: Make the program exit with  `1` if there were differences and `0` means no differences.
- `--quiet`: Disable all output of the program. Implies --exit-code.

So, this command `git diff HEAD^:src/docker-dotnet-app-aks HEAD:src/docker-dotnet-app-aks --exit-code --quiet` will silently check if there are any changes between the first parent of the current commit and the current commit for the `src/docker-dotnet-app-aks` directory. If there are changes, it will exit with `1`, and if there are no changes, it will exit with `0`.

So this is why this command always returns `1` when you commit a change inside the folder , and returns `0` when you commit a change outside the folder.

Comment: agree, I want to use git diff value to decide if downstream stages should run or not and the logic of comparing HEAD-1 with HEAD does not seem correct as it will always be true. e.g. on day 1, Dev1 made a change to service A and the value of HEAD-1 compared with HEAD becomes 1, means on Day1, Service A will be deployed. Now on day2 another Dev changed Service B, Now it will deploy both Service A and B, which defeats the purpose of this exercis

Comment: Hi @DevOps-AS, if you want to implement this logic and your project can clearly split the folders for each service, then you can use `git diff` to compare the contents of the folders containing only one service. Multiple comparisons are made for multiple services. This way you can only deploy services that have changed since the last commit.

Comment: Miao Tian-MSFT that’s my scenario but my issue as explained above will remain the same I.e git diff head minus one and head will always be true. When it’s true it will build package and deploy but I don’t want to repeat building and deploying if it’s already deployed to AKS.

Comment: We have 5-7 services under each app and I’m adding remote repositories of each service then checking them out and then running git diff

Comment: BTW my concern for git diff head minus one and head is general not specific I.e every one who implements this logics to detect changed folders will have same problem. I want to know what additional condition I should add to identify that package is changed but I don’t need to build and deploy coz it’s already deployed